# How to press physical buttons programmatically in android?

Tags: android, keyevent

Is it possible?

I'm trying to develop a voice-controlled screenshot app. Due to security reasons, I figured I cannot take a screenshot from a background service. I thought about taking a screenshot through simulating physical button pressing event but apparently it's not possible to implement in a service as well.

So, I was thinking about a workaround that might work, I started an activity from my service which would simulate 'VolumeDown' and 'Power' buttons to take a screenshot.

```
//Service
//Speech Recognizer onResults method
ArrayList<String> text = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
String result = "screen";

        if (text.get(0).equals(result)) {
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, ScreenshotActivity.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);

        }
```

.

```
//Activity
public class ScreenshotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER));
    this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN));
    }
}
```

I got this error on logcat:

```
Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_POWER, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=210432295, downTime=210432295, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
```

I know even if I would be able to take a screenshot it would be a screenshot of the activity page but I still wonder if I could make this workaround actually work.

Comment: err: KEYCODE_POWER: I think you can't use hardware buttons to manipulate the device. At least without root access

Comment: @Kaan did u got any solution?

Comment: No. There is no way to do it without root access.